# How to build a proper HTTP API call for Matomo

Tags: vba, matomo, piwiktracker

I am new to using APIs but have been reading up on it. My task is to import data from an API into a CSV file. I have created one import string which works (from an example). Despite reading the [documentation](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api) page and the one working example I have not yet gotten the actual report that i need to work.

Here is the string that did work:

```
myURL = "https://admin.metrics.mysite.com/?module=API" _
& "&method=API.get&idSite=9&period=day&date=last30&format=tsv&translateColumnNames=1" _
& "&token_auth=" & myToken
```

What i need is a monthly report of all files that were downloaded.

Here is my last attempt (many variations already tried):

```
Dim myToken As String
myToken = "secrettokenhere"
myURL = "https://admin.metrics.mysite.com/?module=API" _
    & "&method=API.getDownloads" _
    & "&idSite=9" _
    & "&period=day" _
    & "&date=2018-11-05" _
    & "&segement=''" _
    & "&expanded=''" _
    & "&idSubtable=''" _
    & "&flat=''" _
    & "&format=tsv" _
    & "&filter_limit=10" _
    & "&token_auth=" & myToken
```

When I run this, the error message that i get returned is this:

> Error: The method 'getDownloads' does not exist or is not available in
>   the module '\Piwik\Plugins\API\API'.

I'm stuck on the most basic of things... am I using the correct `get` method? Am I missing parameters? What am I doing wrong?

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could mention which programming language you are using.

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but i updated the main question to include the VBA tag as well as the example of the string that worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [API reference](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api), the method is not called `API.getDownloads`, but instead `Actions.getDownloads`.

#### More detail now that I understand your issue better:

The API endpont you are using (`API.get`) gives you a count of the downloads per day, which I don't think is what you want.

The easiest way to get the right endpoint (apart from reading the [API reference](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api)) is opening the report you need in the Matomo UI.
If you want a list of all downloads, this would be the `Behaviour` -> `Downloads` report. Afterwards you can click on the export icon below the table and it will show you the correct API url.

In your case it would now be [`?module=API&method=Actions.getDownloads`](https://demo.matomo.org/?module=API&method=Actions.getDownloads&idSite=3&period=year&date=today&format=json&token_auth=anonymous)

If you don't want a directory, but a flat list you can add `&flat=1`:  [`?module=API&method=Actions.getDownloads&flat=1`](https://demo.matomo.org/?module=API&method=Actions.getDownloads&idSite=3&period=year&date=today&format=html&token_auth=anonymous&flat=1).

This should return what you want (maybe also add `&filter_limit=-1` to get back unlimited results).

Comment: This returns the following message: "Error: The plugin actions is not enabled. You can activate the plugin on Settings &gt; Plugins page in Matomo." Unfortunately, i don't see anyplace where i would be able to change such a setting. Neither am I the admin for the application on the server.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the method i was using previously was itself called API?

Comment: Hi, I have expanded my answer to show the exact API query.

Comment: I arrived at the same answer independently. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help! Your answer is correct!